# How can I edit a tag and its description in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, tags

I wonder how I can access all tags available in WordPress, edit them and their descriptions and save them. Please help me with the coding procedure. I want to use it in my plugin.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far, where have you looked? Have you googled about editing tags programmatically yet? If you're not willing to make an initial effort to do something and show us what you've tried, why should we try to help you? try looking in the wordpress codex first, then edit your question to show us what you've attempted.

Comment: When someone needs help, if you can help him, if not, leave it ...

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you do some more research into the structure of the tags, also know as terms. The [Developer Codex's function reference is a great place to start](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference).

There exists a method [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) which can be used to retrieve terms in any taxonomy. So you need to also get these taxonomies, this can be done programmatically via [get_taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies).

```
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies(array(), 'name'); 
$terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'hide_empty' => false));
```

Once you have these terms it's entirely up to you to determine how you choose what your edits are, such as saying if `term->name == "XXX"` then do Y. But when you need to update the term, you can use the [wp_update_term](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_term) method. If you look at the `args` array in that documentation you'll see that you can update the name, description and what have you just by passing something to it. So something along these lines will update a term:

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $termId = $term->term_id; 
    $taxonomy = $term->taxonomy;
    $newDescription = // Some logic here to figure things out ... 
    wp_update_term($termId, $taxonomy, array('description' => $newDescription);
}
```

Full Disclaimer: I haven't *tried* to run this code, and it's been a while since I looked at the structure of the term objects returned by `get_terms`, so you might want to `var_dump` one of them to determine their fields if you can't find a listing of what they are online.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have searched a lot but I didn't know the similarity between term, tag and category.
Thanks again

Comment: No problem, if you're ever wondering where something is in the WP world a good place to look is at the database schema documentation. It's more obvious that tags/categories and terms are very related from that. There's also a wordpress specific stackexchange site and you can learn a lot from just reading through some of the questions and answers there